# Prove that $c$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove that $c$ - space of all convergent sequences - is seperable.

I believe that $c$ is a subspace of $\ell^1$. 
Now, $\ell^1$ is separable, so $c$ is also separable.

**Edited:**

So let $R$ be a set of all sequences $r=(r_1,r_2, \dots,r_n,r_n,\dots)$ where $r_i$ are rational. $R$ is countable.

Now take $\epsilon >0$ and $x\in c$.
$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so there exists $r \in R$ such that  $\sup_n |r_n-x_n|< \epsilon$

**Edit** I know its wrong..

Comment: Your argument does not hold. The sequence $ \left( \dfrac{1}{n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is convergent but is not an element of $ {\ell^{1}}(\mathbb{N}) $.

Comment: You're right. $\ell^1$ is a subspace of $c$...

Comment: As an intermediate step, show that $c_0$, the space of all sequences converging to $0$ is separable. What is missing to get from $c_0$ to $c$?

Comment: $c_{00}$ is dense in $c_0$. Adding some rational constant

Comment: I've edited first post.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe that $c$ is a subspace of $\ell^1$. 
>   Now, $\ell^1$ is separable, so $c$ is also separable.

The problem is that there are sequences $(a_n)$ which converge to $0$ but so slowly that the series $\sum_n |a_n|$ is divergent.

However, we can consider the subset of sequences with rational entries, and which are eventually constant. This is a countable dense subset.

Comment: I've edited first post.